# SQL - Vlookup version

Tags: sql, vlookup

I need to bring into my main table a value contained in another table, example:

TABLE1

```
Agent Name - Agent ID - Other info`s that I will use
John           1234
Maria          1235
```

TABLE2

```
Agent Name - Agent ID - Rating
John           1234        5
Maria          1235        4
```

FINAL TABLE

```
Agent Name - Agent ID - Rating - Other info`s that I will use
John           1234        5      
Maria          1235        4
```

Also I need to use both Agent Name and Agent ID to bring the info about rating into Table1, how do I do this :(?

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL` vlookup represents via `JOIN`s (i.e. `INNER/LEFT`)  :

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.rating, t2.col, . . . 
from t1 inner join -- may require here `LEFT` join
     t2
     on t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.rating IS NOT NULL; -- IF YOU USE LEFT JOIN
```

`INNER JOIN` will bring the data which are present in both tables.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a left join?

Comment: @RyanSparks, I'd say that's an impossible call. Given the sample data, an inner join is fine. In reality? Probably a left join.

Comment: @EricBrandt - if you are replicating Excel's `VLOOKUP()` functionality it should be left join, although I agree the sample data implies either is fine.

Comment: Now I need to exclude the empty rating values, how can I do that?

Comment: @thalesthales. . . You have two options either do `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` or filter data via `WHERE t2.rating IS NOT NULL`.